# Role based ACL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, acl

I am implementing a role based ACL for an API and I have tables for users, roles, pages, page actions(view, add,edit,delete) and role associations with page actions. Now how can I write a Gate or Policy for Authorizations utilizing these tables and use it in a middleware? Any example is welcome.

I went through the Authorization documentation, but not getting an idea of how to define abilities and check for them in a role based scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this source code as example: [Spatie/Laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission)

Also an example for a middleware to check role or permission:

**can.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
{       
    if(!$request->user()->can($permission)){
        flash()->warning(trans('alert.noAccess'));
        return abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

**role.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role, $permission = null)
{
    if (auth()->guest()) {
        return redirect(route('auth.login'));
    }

    if (!$request->user()->hasRole($role)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Its uses laravel Authorization Gate and that is added in Laravel 5.1.11 so it will work in 5.2